# Get change event of iframe content?

Tags: jquery, events, iframe

I have a div with an iframe which is showing embedded google map,
the map can move, I want to get an event after any change in map image (any navigation) on iframe. can I get it?
Thanks

P.S.: I use jquery library. when I use onload event it fires only the first time!

Comment: What causes the map to change? User interaction?

Comment: You don't really have access to iframes showing cross domain content, but Google Maps has event handlers for just about everything built in, so show us how you initialize the map ?

Comment: User interaction causes map to change.

Comment: i find my place on google map and use google HTML to embed map in my website.

Comment: You'll need to use the Google Maps API to have this kind of control.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't allow interaction between your page and iframe content. Check if Google Maps API provides any useful functions for that:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference